# Regular expression to match all characters on a U.S. keyboard

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern to match all characters that are found on a U.S. keyboard. right now, I match only on letters and numbers and white space, so it looks like

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+$
```

But now I need it to match on any character found on a keyboard. I even want it to match if the string is empty as well.

Comment: What regex engine are you using ?

Comment: What if the user has another keyboard layout? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Good point, Tomalak. US International has all kinds of interesting characters, too :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
  ^[\x00-\x7F]*$
```

for 0-n [ASCII characters](http://www.december.com/html/spec/ascii.html)

```
  ^[\x20-\x7F]*$
```

would be more accurate, as mentioned by [Nick D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108130/nick-d) in the comment: from <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to <kbd>DEL</kbd>.

As detailed in [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html):

> \xFF where FF are 2 hexadecimal digits
>
> Matches the character with the specified ASCII/ANSI value, which depends on the code page used. Can be used in [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

`[\x20-\x7F]` is a character class specifying here a range of characters.

Comment: shouldn't `^[\x20-\x7E]*$` be more appropriate?