# Rendering issue for combined font (Japanese & English ) in PDF using cfdocument

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, fonts, font-face, cfdocument

I have big trouble with "Combined Fonts" (Japanese & English).

I have to create a PDF document from HTML content which is shown in my website. For that I have used `<cfdocument>` and implemented the PDF from the HTML content. But my content includes both Japanese & English content and which is appear in a different font in the created PDF than what is on my website. The issue occurred only in the case of combined Japanese & English section.

The requirement is:

- For English content, the font should be Verdana.
- For Japanese content, the font should be Simson.

I have implemented the same with Korean, Chinese, French and it's working.

For outputting the special characters, I have added `<cfprocessingDirective pageEncoding="utf-8">` above the code. But I still get weird font for the contents in both English and Japanese.

The code I have tried is given below,

```
        <cfcontent type="application/pdf">
        <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=test.pdf">
        <cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
        <cfdocument format="PDF" localurl="yes" marginTop=".25" marginLeft=".25" marginRight=".25" marginBottom=".25" pageType="custom" pageWidth="8.5" pageHeight="10.2">
        <cfoutput>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
         <title>PDF Export Example</title>
         <style>
          body { font-family: Verdana; }
          h1 { font-size: 14px; }
          p { font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.25em; margin-left:20px;}
           </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>PDF Export Example Combined Japanese & English</h1>
        <p>This is an japanese with english example 
        日本人は単純な音素配列論で膠着、モーラ·タイミングの言語、純粋な母音システム、
        音素の母音と子音の長さ、および語彙的に重要なピッチアクセント。語順は通常、粒子が言葉の文法的機能をマ
        ーキング対象オブジェクトと動詞であり、文の構造は、トピック·コメントです。文末粒子は、感情的または強調の影響を追加したり、
        質問を作るために使用されます。名詞は文法的に番号や性別を持たず、何の記事はありません。動詞は主に緊張し、音声ではなく、
        人のために、コンジュゲートされる。形容詞の日本の同等物は、また、結合している。日本人は動詞の形や語彙、話者の相対的な地位、
        リスナーおよび掲げる者を示すと敬語の複雑なシステムを持っています。This is an example.
        </p>
        <h1>PDF Export English Example</h1>
        <p>This is an example.
        </p>
        </body>
        </html>
        </cfoutput>
        </cfdocument>
```

What else should I do to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you pls not simply describe the code, but post a portable repro case so we can see what you're doing. Reading: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: I have updated my Question with the code i have tried. Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the results I have got and research, I have found that there is an issue with PDF style rendering for English with Japanese content.

So finally I found a solution,

1. Apply space between the Japanese and English words.
2. Iterate the whole string ([list](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/Tags_j-l_15.html) with space delimiter)
3. Then It is possible to differentiate the English words from the Japanese words by [Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444666/regular-expression-to-match-all-characters-on-a-u-s-keyboard)
4. Apply separate style for English words by wrapping them by [span](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) (or any) tag.

I don't know whether this is the proper solution for this issue. This is what I have done for solving the issue.